# force a rerender on a visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have some code that grabs info using an ActionFunction. I then take the returned value and try to put it in an input box.

```
apex:inputField value="{!Loan__c.ContactID__c}" id="cid" onblur="checkContact(this.value);" />`
```

checkContact checks the contact then fills an inputbox dynamically. However when actionfunction rerenders the first time. It doesn't retreive the data. The second time it finally does. Is there anyway to force the rerender at the same time as the finishing of the actionfunction? Or am i looking at using a remoteAction

```
<apex:actionFunction immediate="true" name="checkContact" action="{!checkContact}" id="checkContact" rerender="cidtext,template">
    <apex:param name="contactToCheck" assignTo="{!contactToCheck}" value="" id="contactToCheck" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Comment: Can you please post your actionfunction code

Comment: I think in your apex function you are assigning the id to "Loan__c.ContactID__c" and then rerendering the parent element of <apex:inputField>. am I right?